# How to populate MULTIPLE sub data using .populate().exec()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to populate 2 sub data. My attempt fails, need some help.

This is what I have:

`let foundBook = await Book.findById(req.params.bookid).populate("entries", "comments").exec(); res.render("book/bookshow", {book: foundBook});`

This is the model. I'd like to populate entries and comments:

`entries: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Entry"}], comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is this:

```js
let foundBook = await Book.findById(req.params.bookid)
                          .populate("entries")
                          .populate("comments").exec();
```